# проблема с регулярным выражением для формирования url

Tags: python, django

Есть такое

```
url(r'^articles/get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', views.article)
```

Должен получаться такой адресс по идее:

```
/articles/get/1/
```

Но на выходе при клике:

```
/articles/get1/
```

В чем трабл?

```
def article(request, article_id=1):
return render(request, 'article.html', {'article': Article.objects.get(id=article_id),
'comments': Comments.objects.filter(comments_article_id=article_id)})

<h4><a href="/articles/get/{{article.id}}">{{ article.article_title}}</a></h4>
```

Comment: А где собственно код получения адреса?

Comment: Сорян, я значит не понимаю чего-то, но мне казалось, что  эта часть , url(r'^articles/get/(?P<article_id>\d+)/$', views.article), собственно и есть формирование урл, и вот эта статичная часть остается неизменой (r'^articles/get/, я не понимаю каким боком генерится id перед слешем в блоке /get/ . Обновил тело вопроса, вставил код как именно вытягивается id из бд, правда не понимаю как это может помочь

Comment: Есть-то она есть, только вот вы никак её не используете. Чтобы эта часть использовалась, вы должны где-то в шаблоне написать что-то похожее на `{% url 'article' article.id %}`, но у вас такого не видно. Перечитайте [документацию Django](https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/intro/tutorial03.html#removing-hardcoded-urls-in-templates) про то, как нужно правильно работать с url

Comment: Пару раз перезугриз сервер все заработало, вот не знаю шо за хрень) в любом случае спасибо